# On focus, do customized focus on textarea

Tags: jquery

My Code:

```
$('#myTextArea').one('focus', function() {
     $('#myTextArea')[0].selectionStart = 2;
     $('#myTextArea')[0].selectionEnd = 6;
     $('#myTextArea')[0].focus();
});
```

The code works fine, on focus (only once), it selects from index 2 to 6.

The problem: since this function is called on focus, it does the custom focus, but then it calls focus AGAIN and I lose focus of the selected text. Any possible solution?

Comment: Try defining the focus function as empty? That might work. Just like $("#myTextArea").focus(function(){});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why this works but I think it might just do the trick:

```
$('#myTextArea').bind("focus mousedown", "click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).select();
    this.selectionStart = 2;
    this.selectionEnd = 6;
});
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQHt4/)

Comment: The binding made it work! btw, preventDefault() and .select() are unnecessary, it works without them :)

Comment: Just to clarify: This works because it's acting on the click instead of the focus event. Tabbing to the textarea (which is effectively the focus event without the click) doesn't make the selection.

Comment: Also, beware that `.selectionStart` and `.selectionEnd` isn't completely cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already binding to the `focus` event and you aren't preventing the default behavior, you shouldn't need to fire `.focus()` manually. Try this instead:

```
$('#myTextArea').one('focus', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     this.selectionStart = 2;
     this.selectionEnd = 6;
});
```

Comment: it does the custom focus, but then it automatically-immediately do the default focus, which cause the textarea to lose my custom focus. Is there a way to prevent the default focus?

Comment: I updated my answer with `event.preventDefault()`, give that a whirl!

Comment: You added the `event` argument to the callback function, too, right? e.g. `...function(event) {...`

Comment: Yes, it didn't do any effect :(

Comment: Seems you're right. I can do the effect selecting text in another textarea, but not the one being focused. Odd.